# Load ColdFusion values from Form scope when name includes hyphen/dash

Tags: coldfusion

We're upgrading to Google's reCaptcha and it adds a field with name "g-recaptcha-response" to the form during submit. We them need to verify the response to Google with code like this:

```
<cfhttp url="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify" method="post" result="captchaResult">
  <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="secret" value="SECRET"> 
  <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="response" value="#Form.g-recaptcha-response#"> 
  <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="remoteip" value="#CGI.REMOTE_ADDR#"> 
</cfhttp>
```

However, the `#Form.g-recaptcha-response#` gives `Element G is undefined in FORM.`

Is there another way to reference Form scope to allow hyphens?

Answer (score 4):

That will give you an error if the form variable doesn't exist.  Try this instead:

```
<CFSET Form.Response = "">
<CFIF StructKeyExists(Form, "g-recaptcha-response")>
   <CFSET Form.Response = form["g-recaptcha-response"]>
</CFIF>
```

I wrote a reCAPTCHA v2 UDF yesterday. I wanted to support sToken so I could use the same API key on multiple websites.

http://gist.github.com/JamoCA/c4e83ca402bd6175a1d7

Comment: *a reCAPTCHA v2 UDF* Nice one!

Comment: Some CFdevs may argue that it would be better served as a custom tag, but it's easy enough to convert to that if desired. (I use these UDFs in a global library that is included in most projects.)

Comment: Personally, I prefer the UDF approach too, but like you said, easy enough to modify as needed.

Answer (score 3):

Just found a solution:

```
  <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="response" value="#Form["g-recaptcha-response"]#">
```